# Return multiple values to a function, and access them separately in Lua?

Tags: lua

If I have a function that returns multiple values, how can I access those values separately? Something like table[i].

```
angles = function()
    x = function()
        local value = 0
        return value
    end

    y = function()
        local value = 90
        return value
    end

    z = function()
        local value = 180
        return value
    end

    return x(), y(), z()
end
```

A problem arises here when wanting to use, for example, the `x` value separately, while keeping it in the function `angles`.

```
print(????)
```

Sort of wish functions worked like tables in this respect, so I could type something like `print(angles.x)`

Also, I know that code seems really redundant, but it's actually a much more simplified version of what I'm actually using. Sorry if it makes less sense that way.

Comment: Note that `x`, `y` and `z` will be global functions, callable from outside `angles`. You should probably declare them local.

Comment: Your function definitions would be more readable if you used the "function funcName() ... end" form. See http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.11

Comment: Thanks. I did make them local in my actual code, and I was never really sure which style was right for functions within functions. I see it done differently all the time and I often have internal conflict over these things. angles is actually in another function as well, but the the overarching ones are in the format you've suggested. Thanks, for the suggestions though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x, y, z= angles()
print (x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of ways to do this.

Most obvious would be

```
local x, y, z = angles()
print(x)
```

If you want the first value specifically

```
local x = ( angles() )
-- `local x = angles()` would work too. Lua discards excess return values.
print(x)
```

or, somewhat less readably

```
print((angles()))
```

You could also return a table from the function, or use the standard module `table` to pack the return values into one.

```
local vals = table.pack(angles())
print(vals[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way of accessing them individually (as the question wording implies) rather than all at once is this:

```
print((select(1,angles())))
print((select(2,angles())))
print((select(3,angles())))
```

Output:

```
0
90
180
```

The `select()` call **needs to be in parentheses** in order to return individual entries rather than *all after the given offset*.